# How to concat multiple values that belong to the same index into one cell with Python?

Tags: excel, dataframe, data-cleaning

So I have this dataframe:

| ID | Prize |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Gold |
| 123 | Silver |
| 654 | Gold |
| 654 | Silver |
| 654 | Bronze |
| 789 | Silver |
| 789 | Bronze |

But I need to concatenate the prices that belong to the same ID in one cell like this:

| ID | Prize |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Gold,Silver |
| 654 | Gold,Silver,Bronze |
| 789 | Silver,Bronze |

Do you know how to go about this?

Comment: I suggest using a conditional `TEXTJOIN()`, as described here: https://sfmagazine.com/post-entry/april-2018-excel-using-textjoin-with-an-array/#:~:text=Type%20%3DTEXTJOIN(%E2%80%9C%2C%20%E2%80%9D,or%20edit%20an%20array%20formula.

Comment: I forgot to specify this is with python lol